# Repeating loop when condition is true with same vaule

Tags: matlab, loops

I have this loop construction and every single value with index `k` of the vector is loaded each by the time.
I want to get managed that when the condition 3 is true he restarts the loop with the same used value after it calculated the function. I tried something like `k=k-1`in the condition but it didn't work out. Any ideas?

```
v=[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,...]

for k=1:n
    if condition1
        Function1
    elseif condition2
        Function2
    elseif condition3 
        Function3
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that I though you could do that in matlab. Maybe it stores it as a separate variable which you can not modify in the loop.

Try with a while loop, although I would recommend that you be careful not to cause infinite loop.

```
k = 1;
while k<=n
    if condition1
        Function1
        k=k+1;
    elseif condition2
        Function2
        k=k+1;
    elseif condition3
        Function3
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, this helps! Do you know how I do run this loop exactly 2 times?

Comment: well in that case you can introduce more variables, and the `while` statement can check multiple conditions. Not exactly sure of the logic but I am sure you can figure it out.